# Unable to set cookie in browser using request and express modules in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, browser

I am having a client and a server node written in express. The client communicates with server using request module, the server will send response back to the client. Here in server code I am sending cookie back to the client. But I am unable to see the cookies in the browser. In client req.cookies is giving {}

Server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/test-cookie', function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('abc', 'xyz').send('Cookie is set');
});
app.listen(9000);
```

Client code:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/test-cookie',
        method: 'GET'
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({
                msg: error
            });
        } else {
            if (200 == response.statusCode) {
                console.log(req.cookies);
            }
        }
    });
});
app.listen(7000);
```

Answer (score 0):

response.cookies is to SET cookies, if you want to GET cookies from a response object you will have to rely on response.headers['set-cookie']

Answer (score 0):

Client browser for first hit to `7000` api will not contain any cookie, thus `req.cookies` will log `{}`, thus we have to set cookie in the `res` for the client browser to send the cookie for the rest requests.

**Solution** (Client Code):

```
if (200 == response.statusCode) {

    // For first request it will be empty {}
    console.log(req.cookies);

    /* fetching the cookie from the response header
     * and setting in res to be set in the browser
     */
    var c = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    res.set('set-cookie',c[0]);

    res.send('Done');

}
```

**Explanation**:
What you are doing is trying to fetch cookies from `req` which does not contain any cookie. The `response` object you are getting from hitting the `9000` api will contain the cookie. Thus, you have to set the cookie from `response` to the `res` for client browser.