# fetch: Getting cookies from fetch response

Tags: express, cookies, fetch

I'm trying to implement client login using fetch on react.

I'm using passport for authentication. The reason I'm using `fetch` and not regular `form.submit()`, is because I want to be able to recieve error messages from my express server, like: `"username or password is wrong"`.

I know that passport can send back messages using `flash` messages, but `flash` requires sessions and I would like to avoid them.

This is my code:

```
fetch('/login/local', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.headers.get('set-cookie')); // undefined
      console.log(document.cookie); // nope
      return res.json();
    }).then(json => {
      if (json.success) {
        this.setState({ error: '' });
        this.context.router.push(json.redirect);
      }
      else {
        this.setState({ error: json.error });
      }
    });
```

The server sends the cookies just fine, as you can see on chrome's dev tools:
[image: Network - Cookies]
[image: Network - Headers]

But chrome doesn't set the cookies, in Application -> Cookies -> localhost:8080: "The site has no cookies".

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: can you post the code of your server side?

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035445/unable-to-set-cookie-in-browser-using-request-and-express-modules-in-nodejs/36038537

Comment: Found out the problem, see my answer. Thanks, btw.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the fetch option `credentials: same-origin/include` not being set.
As the fetch documentation mentions this option to be required for sending cookies on the request, it failed to mention this when reading a cookie.

So I just changed my code to be like this:

```
fetch('/login/local', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    }).then(res => {
      return res.json();
    }).then(json => {
      if (json.success) {
        this.setState({ error: '' });
        this.context.router.push(json.redirect);
      }
      else {
        this.setState({ error: json.error });
      }
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me , even after setting the  credentials: 'same-origin',/'include.

Comment: This does not work even with the credentials as same-origin

Comment: credentials: 'same-origin' is the default value, no? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials

Comment: Not working  credentials: 'same-origin' or 'include'

Comment: I fixed this by setting credentials: 'include' and also setting the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "http://localhost:3000" (my Webstorm is serving the react pages from a different server than my express server) and also setting the header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" to "true"

Comment: I did as Mark above, but it didn't work for me. But it turns out you can just access `document.cookie`; here's how I accessed a JWT inside a bearer token set-cookie Authorization response: 
```const cookie = document.cookie;const findAuthorization = 'Authorization=';const startIndex = cookie.indexOf(findAuthorization) + findAuthorization.length;const endIndex = cookie.indexOf(';', startIndex) ?? cookie.length - 1;const rawJwt = cookie.slice(startIndex, endIndex).split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: This answer doesn't actually show how to get a cookie value from the response, which was the original question.

Answer (score 8):

From **Differences from jQuery** section of [the Fetch API on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#differences_from_jquery):

- fetch() **won't receive cross-site cookies.** You can’t establish a cross
  site session using fetch(). Set-Cookie headers from other sites are
  silently ignored.
- fetch() **won’t send cookies**, unless you set the
  credentials init option. *Since Aug 25, 2017: The spec changed the
  default credentials policy to same-origin. Firefox changed since
  61.0b13.)*

Answer (score 1):

I had to include `credentials: 'include'` in the `fetch` options:

```js
fetch('...', {
  ...
  credentials: 'include', // Need to add this header.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I spent a long time but nothing worked for me.

after trying several solutions online this one worked for me.

Hopefully it will work for you too.

```
{
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "API-Key",
  },
  credentials: "include",
}
```