# How to access the value from set-cookie in React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, setcookie, traccar

I've been working on a project using [Traccar API](https://www.traccar.org/traccar-api/) and React.

My problem is that I want to save the value of **set-cookie** response Header, to store it in the browser's cookies.

I want to do this because, neither Firefox or Chrome set the cookie on the browser.

[image: Cookie not set]

But on both browsers I get the same response Header.

[image: Response header]

This is my function, and as you can see, I tried to get the value of **set-cookie** using `response.headers.get()`

```
    const login = async () => {

        setLoading(true);
        const myHeaders = new Headers();

        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic Og==");
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


        var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
        urlencoded.append("email", user.email);
        urlencoded.append("password", user.password);

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: urlencoded,
            credentials: 'include',
            redirect: 'manual',
        }

        trackPromise(
            fetch("http://x.x.x.x:7082/api/session", requestOptions)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        console.log('Cookie: '+response.headers.get('set-cookie'))
                        redirect();
                    } else {
                        alert('There was a problem');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
        );
    }
```

But everytime I call the request, the result is the same.

[image: Null value]

Also, i tried to modify the `credentials` Header and using `credentials: include`,`credentials: same-origin` and `credentials: omit`, but still no luck.

I've been stuck with this problem for over a week, One of the things that I have noticed is that when testing the API methods in Postman, the **JSESSIONID** value, which come from **set-cookie**, is always used, this value is returned as a Response Header, but in the Code Snippets, is also set as a Request Header, that makes sense because every method on the API using Postman uses it as a Request Header.

So, how to get this value?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar [fetch: Getting cookies from fetch response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188376/fetch-getting-cookies-from-fetch-response)

Check what headers you can read:

```
fetch(URL, { credentials: 'include' })
 .then((response) => {
  
  for(let entry of response.headers.entries()) {
    console.log('header', entry);
  }
});
```

If cookies was already set, try to access them as `document.cookies`.
(it won'r work for cookies that flagged as httpOnly)

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. these are the headers that I can actually read, are         ```content-lenght```, ```content-type``` and ```expires```, but document cookies is still blank, do you think it has something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8069697/7055653) ?

Comment: Yes, httpOnly blocks them from being read from javascript because of security reasons. but credentialsInclude will pass them to backend automatically