# Antiforgery implementation with react in non-mvc project failing POST request

Tags: reactjs, localhost, asp.net-core-6.0, antiforgerytoken

So far I have reviewed the following information.
[link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188376/fetch-getting-cookies-from-fetch-response)
[Tutorial with demo](https://readdy.net/Notes/Details/2006)

1. Configurations.

================

Only listing relevant configurations for:

**server side http://localhost:2000**
Startup.cs

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
                options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
}
```

===

```
services.AddCors ....
.WithExposedHeaders("X-XSRF-TOKEN")
```

==

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                if (string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    HttpMethods.IsPost(context.Request.Method) ||
                    HttpMethods.IsPut(context.Request.Method) ||
                    HttpMethods.IsDelete(context.Request.Method))
                {
                    var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);

                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokenSet.RequestToken!,
                       new CookieOptions
                       {
                           HttpOnly = false,
                           Secure = false,
                           IsEssential = true,
                           SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
                       });
                }

                return next(context);
            });
```

**Client side http://localhost:1000**

```
 headers.append('X-XSRF-TOKEN', getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN'));
 headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
```

2. POST call has credentials: 'include' .This end point is never hit because it has attribute [ValidateAntiforgeryToken]. If removed the API works fine.

================

3. Debugging

================

Network tab when debugging.
Network/Header Tab
Under response Header I see

Set-Cookie:

XSRF-TOKEN=*token1*path=/api; samesite=lax; httponly

Set-Cookie:
XSRF-TOKEN=*token2*

Under request Header I see

Cookie:

XSRF-TOKEN=*token3*_mkto_trk=id:417-HWY-826&token:_mch-localhost-1699799039514-29092;

XSRF-TOKEN=*token4*

X-Xsrf-Token:
*token4*

Network/Cookies tab
Request cookies

XSRF-TOKEN value *token1*

XSRF-TOKEN value *token4*

_mkto_trk

Response cookies

XSRF-TOKEN value *token1*

Application tab

XSRF-TOKEN value *token1*

XSRF-TOKEN value *token2*

_mkto_trk

4. Attempted

================

This code response.headers.get('Set-Cookie') returns null to me. Based on the investigation made they say, it is not possible to read that value.
So instead I am doing.

```
const cookies = document.cookie;
    if (cookies) {
        const cookieValue = document.cookie
        .split('; ')
        .find(row => row.startsWith(name))
        ?.split('=')[1];
        return cookieValue;
    }
```

5. I keep getting error 400 in my POST resquest.

================

6. I have added antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context) within the app.Use without success.

================

7. Token API

================

I have tried to generate a token6 and include it in the header with a get request as follows but it also response with error 400.

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAntiForgeryToken()
        {
            var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
            return Ok(new { xsrfToken = headerToken });
            }
```

I tried to hard code tokens across the project but .ValidateRequestAsync seems to generate its own token and my POST fails.

Do I have too many tokens?

Maybe I need https instead?

Please, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Normally, we protect .NET Core APIs with token-based authentication rather than cookie-based authentication, are you sure it is necessary to add antiforgery validation in your API project? you can check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#token-based-authentication) to know more about CSRF attack.