# Unable to access cookie from fetch() response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, setcookie

Even though this question is asked several times at ***SO*** like:

[fetch: Getting cookies from fetch response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188376/fetch-getting-cookies-from-fetch-response)

or

[Unable to set cookie in browser using request and express modules in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035445/unable-to-set-cookie-in-browser-using-request-and-express-modules-in-nodejs/36038537)

None of this solutions could help me getting the cookie from a `fetch()` response

My setup looks like this:

### Client

```
export async function registerNewUser(payload) {
    return fetch('https://localhost:8080/register',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
}

...
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    registerNewUser({...values, avatarColor: generateAvatarColor()}).then(response => {
        console.log(response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')); // null
        console.log(response.headers.get('cookie')); //null
        console.log(document.cookie); // empty string
        console.log(response.headers); // empty headers obj
        console.log(response); // response obj
    }).then(() => setValues(initialState))
}
```

### server

```
private setUpMiddleware() {
    this.app.use(cookieParser());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
        credentials: true
    }));
    this.app.use(express.static(joinDir('../web/build')));
}
...
this.app.post('/register', (request, response) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, avatarColor, email, password }: User = request.body;
    this.mongoDBClient.addUser({ firstName, lastName, avatarColor, email, password } as User)
        .then(() => {
            const token = CredentialHelper.JWTSign({email}, `${email}-${new Date()}`);
            response.cookie('token', token, {httpOnly: true}).sendStatus(200); // tried also without httpOnly
        })
        .catch(() => response.status(400).send("User already registered."))
})
```

[image]

Comment: `httpOnly: true`, prevents clientside access

Comment: Even though I removed this option value on the server side/directly set it to false. The client logs still the same values...

Comment: Have you confirmed you're indeed getting cookied from the backend? This is usually visible in your browser's devtools

Comment: updated my question accordingly.. Yes I checked that too.

Comment: That cookie appears to still be HTTPOnly.

Comment: This time it is really not...

Comment: I  DID NOT!!!! The image above is a validation of the network response from chrome dev tools!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution was to set credentials to `'include'` like so:

```
export async function registerNewUser(payload) {
    return fetch('https://localhost:8080/register',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
}
```

After that I needed to enabled credentials in my cors middleware:

```
    this.app.use(cors({
            credentials: true, // important part here
            origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
            optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
        })
```

And then finally I needed to remove the option `{httpOnly: true}` in the express route response:

```
response.cookie('token', '12345ssdfsd').sendStatus(200);
```

Keep in mind if you send the cookie like this, it is set directly to the clients cookies. You can now see that the cookie is set with: `console.log(document.cookie)`.

But in a practical environment you don't want to send a cookie that is accessible by the client. You should usually use the `{httpOnly: true}` option.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `fetch` method won't send client side cookies and silently ignores the cookies sent from Server side [Reference link in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), so you may use `XMLHttpRequest` method to send the request from your client side.